# Java code prints the x[1] -> x[n-1] in reverse correctly but the first and last were the same. How do I print the reverse correctly?

Tags: reverse

Here's my code!
This is a homework. Thanks.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Recursion {
    public static void main(String [] args){        
        int t = Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input a number(1-4): "));
        String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input sequence of strings: ");

        String[] toReverse = s.split(" ");

        if(t==1){
            for(String retVal : s.split(" ")){
                System.out.println(retVal);
                int i = 0;
                toReverse[i] = retVal;
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println("The reversal is");
            reverse(toReverse);
            for(String retVal1 : toReverse){
                System.out.println(retVal1);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void reverse(String[] x){
        if(x.length==2){
            String first = x[0];
            x[0] = x[1];
            x[1] = first;
        }
        else if(x.length > 2){
            String first = x[0];
            x[0]= x[x.length-1];
            x[x.length-1] = first;
            String[] copy = new String[x.length-2];
            System.arraycopy(x, 1, copy, 0, x.length-2);
            reverse(copy);
            System.arraycopy(copy, 0, x, 1, copy.length);
        }
    }
}
```

i need to get an output like:
the
quick
brown
fox
The reversal is
fox
brown
quick
the

but I get

the
quick
brown
fox
The reversal is
fox
brown
quick
fox

Comment: `toReverse[i] = retVal;` what does this do exactly? Why do you need it?

Comment: i can't remember when i put it on there but when i delete it it worked fine. thank you so much! @n.m.